How can the CMOS version of 555 timer have the output current tested at 2 mA while its maximum supply is 250 μA?
As per the Datasheet of LMC555, the maximum supply current is 250 μA @ 5 volt supply voltage.
How come the output current reach 2 mA, I mean where did the IC get the extra (2*1000-250) μA?
Maybe I miss something or misunderstand these attributes at the datasheet, so it will be helpful if anyone clarify this.

On page 5 :


I was thinking about using the CMOS version of the 555 timer to create a variable duty cycle 150 kHz square wave generator to drive a MOSFET in order to learn designing flyback converter and SMPS in general.
But the issue is that I need very low current 555 timer, so that I can drive it using simple resistor or couple or resistors in parallel from the mains after rectifying and smoothing the current. I needed the CMOS low current version so that the resistance can handle the power (current and voltage across it) without burning.
I didn't like to use the offline switching IC because it can be blown easily while learning and due to its higher cost. So how can I know the output current at 5 volts exactly from the datasheet at 5 V, and how can I solve the contradiction I felt and highlighted in yellow?

All switches open, it says.

Note that many other devices are spec'd in a similar fashion.  '485 & LVDS drivers, for example, usually don't include the load current (through a termination resistor) in their supply specification.

The 250 μA is the maximum at 5 V what the chip itself consumes with no load. (Note also that the 555 timer chip can produce some output current on other pins – even the other pins are unloaded in this test.)
When the chip is driving 2 mA out into a load, it will take max 2.25 mA in and uses at most 0.25 mA for itself and drives the 2 mA out.

The "maximum supply current" is only the current used internally by the timer chip. Any output current gets added to this.

Thanks dave , i have accepted other answer with same meaning of your answer since it was posted first according to time stamp .. but thanks

It wasn't, but that's okay.

Thanks any way .. sorry for that
